# Unable to push to unqualified destination with semantic-release

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, semantic-release

I'm trying to release my library from Jenkins job using semantic-release, but I get this error:

> error: unable to push to unqualified destination: origin/semantic-release-test

From my local machine, I have no problem. This is the full log:

```
    [14:35:42] [semantic-release] › ✔  Run automated release from branch origin/semantic-release-test
2019-05-16T14:35:42.420Z semantic-release:git Error: Command failed: git push --dry-run ssh://git@bitbucket.company.com/path/to/my/repo.git HEAD:origin/semantic-release-test
error: unable to push to unqualified destination: origin/semantic-release-test
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@bitbucket.company.com/path/to/my/repo.git'


    at makeError (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/AppDesign/jobs/semantic-release POC/workspace/node_modules/semantic-release/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at Promise.all.then.arr (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/AppDesign/jobs/semantic-release POC/workspace/node_modules/semantic-release/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
2019-05-16T14:35:42.510Z semantic-release:git Error: Command failed: git push --dry-run ssh://git@bitbucket.company.com/path/to/my/repo.git HEAD:origin/semantic-release-test
error: unable to push to unqualified destination: origin/semantic-release-test
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@bitbucket.company.com/path/to/my/repo.git'


    at makeError (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/AppDesign/jobs/semantic-release POC/workspace/node_modules/semantic-release/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at Promise.all.then.arr (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/AppDesign/jobs/semantic-release POC/workspace/node_modules/semantic-release/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
2019-05-16T14:35:42.611Z semantic-release:git Error: Command failed: git merge-base --is-ancestor  HEAD
fatal: Not a valid object name undefined


    at makeError (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/AppDesign/jobs/semantic-release POC/workspace/node_modules/semantic-release/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at Promise.all.then.arr (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/AppDesign/jobs/semantic-release POC/workspace/node_modules/semantic-release/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
2019-05-16T14:35:42.611Z semantic-release:git Error: Command failed: git merge-base --is-ancestor  HEAD
fatal: Not a valid object name undefined


    at makeError (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/AppDesign/jobs/semantic-release POC/workspace/node_modules/semantic-release/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at Promise.all.then.arr (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/AppDesign/jobs/semantic-release POC/workspace/node_modules/semantic-release/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
[14:35:42] [semantic-release] › ℹ  The local branch origin/semantic-release-test is behind the remote one, therefore a new version won't be published.
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: See https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/issues/1181

Comment: Thanks @PierreVanduynslager, actually I created that issue :)